# is it possible to manipulate the text in the url bar from firefox addon?

Tags: url, firefox, firefox-addon, browser

I am working on a small firefox addon that have to copy selected text to the url bar. I tried this code to test how I could manipulate the url bar:

```
gBrowser.selectedBrowser.currentURI =  Services.io.newURI("about:home", null, null);
```

But that doesn't seem to do anything, does anyone has a sample on how to manipulate the url bar text?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that it can't be done.  I base this on the paucity of relevant results in the search `awesomebar methods properties`, and also from imagining the types of [mischief](http://www.fraudwatchinternational.com/phishing-fraud/phishing-web-site-methods/#hover) that would ensue if Mozilla did make the AwesomeBar writeable.  Also [Mozilla describes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Property/selectedBrowser) `selectedBrowser` that you deploy above as a "read-only property."

The best suggestion I can come up with is Helbrax' [reinvention of that particular wheel](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27079/JavaScript-Awesome-Bar).

Depending on what it is you are trying to accomplish, *[Changing autocomplete behavior - Firefox](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Changing_autocomplete_behavior_-_Firefox)* might help.